# jQuery instead of moving left. it fades. Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a simple slider but I couldn't figure out one thing. 
I want it to fade in and out instead of moving left.

I think I have been missing something.

Thank you for your time. The code bellow if you can help me out let me know.

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            fadeto: + slideWidth
        }, 500, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            fadeTo: - slideWidth
        }, 500, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m7rfdfoa/

Comment: on my system its moving to left direction

Comment: Yeah but I want it to fade instead moving left. 
Fade in and out.

Comment: then don't use slide concent..just fadeout current and fadein `.next()`

Comment: Can you provide fiddle. So I can see the changes exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the function you dont need to find width, height and no need to slideleft or right because if you move a div with margin it will only give slide effect. You can just `.fadeOut()` current div and `.fadeIn()` next div.

Here is short and correct jquery for `moveRight()` and `moveLeft()` function with fade effect

```
function moveRight(){
    $('#slider ul li.active').fadeOut();
    $('#slider ul li.active').next().addClass('active').fadeIn();
    $('#slider ul li.active').eq(0).removeClass('active');
  }
  function moveLeft(){
    $('#slider ul li.active').fadeOut();
    $('#slider ul li.active').prev().addClass('active').fadeIn();
    $('#slider ul li.active').eq(1).removeClass('active');
  }
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/m7rfdfoa/1/

Comment: It's kinda of glitchy somehow. 

It appears at the buttom when it fades out and than it goes up.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't "fadeto" be "fadeTo" in the moveLeft function?

Comment: I tried both but It didn't seem to work. I think I am missing something the animate part.

Comment: I think you are implementing the fadeTo function incorrectly. [fadeTo Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)